# AnyChart Bar Graph with scroll in Mobile (Android or iOS)?

Tags: javascript, java, android, charts, anychart

I have a chart made with AnyChart library in Android and iOS. The problem is, the only scroller available is a bar that is shown under the chart. That is not very user friendly. Is there a way to scroll the chart (x-axis), with the touch in the screen? I really need to make this work as fast as possible.

This are the settings I inserted to zoom my chart, to not appear all the info on top of each other, and to not be shown the zoom under the chart in the x axis.

```
cartesian.xScroller().allowRangeChange(false);
cartesian.xScroller().thumbs().enabled(false);
cartesian.xZoom(true);
cartesian.xZoom(2);
```